# thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'zip: InvalidArchive("Could not find central directory end")',

Tags: django, migration, archive

I am new to using Django and am taking over a repo for my internship that no one currently at the company has worked on. I am working on installing the repo and getting the development environment to work at all. The instructions on the repo's README seem to be outdated. I am following them, but get the following errors when I run `pipenv run python ./manage.py migrate`  I am not sure what "archive" refers to here and what the program is even attempting to do when it encounters this error, and have no idea how to go about fixing it.

````
Loading .env environment variables...
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'zip: InvalidArchive("Could not find central directory end")', /home/runner/.cargo/git/checkouts/divvunspell-1de7e297f42b53b7/474c74a/divvunspell/src/archive/zip.rs:75:51
note: run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display a backtrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/_init_.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/_init_.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 387, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 65, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in _get_
    res = instance._dict_[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in _get_
    res = instance._dict_[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/_init_.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/recvalsite/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    urlpatterns = [path("admin/", admin.site.urls), path("", include("validation.urls"))]
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/_init_.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/validation/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/validation/views.py", line 76, in <module>
    from .helpers import (
  File "/cshome/bsapara/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface/validation/helpers.py", line 26, in <module>
    archive = divvunspell.SpellerArchive(fspath(settings.BASE_DIR / "crk.zhfst"))
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: zip: InvalidArchive("Could not find central directory end")
bsapara@ohaton:~/Documents/ALT/recording-validation-interface>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the project's aim in particular, but it seems like this file `"crk.zhfst"` is not existent in your project but the code is looking for it.

```py
archive = divvunspell.SpellerArchive(fspath(settings.BASE_DIR / "crk.zhfst"))
```

I would recommend: Search with your IDE the entire project for above line of code and then try to understand what's happening there. Maybe you just have to fix the path, maybe you have to add the entire file.

Comment: Ahh thank you, I don't have this file so I think this could be the problem!